# Creating migrations on a web server Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

I have pushed my laravel installation to a web server. To make new migrations, do I need to make them locally and then push them to the appropriate folder on the web server, or is there another way to access the php artisan commands?

Comment: I have the feeling you are just beginning with laravel. Maybe even new in coding? Anyway the documentation should be helpful https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/artisan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not have migrations locally how can you test them?

Your migration files are part of you source code. You create them in development and they are added to version control.
The moment you deploy your installation (With capistrano for example) you run the migrations with

```
php artisan migrate
```

This command is run from the root of your application.

Comment: where should i write it (when i'm in an online server) ?

Comment: The root of your application folder. Same place where your app, public, folder is. If there is an artisan file present you can run it.

Comment: @hassenzouari: php artisan migrate is a terminal command so you need to run it in the terminal also making sure that you are in the root folder that is the parent directory of app.

Comment: @hassenzouari this is getting ridiculous. Is it a linux or windows server? Do you have an ssh connection? Have you ever worked in a terminal. How did you develop the application locally? Like I suggested first create the migrations locally and try to run them from there before going to a remote server.

Comment: @DavidMaes windows , yes , no ,  It's online from the first (A freelancer do the work for me) ... I just want add 2 columns in the datebase ... should i use migration ??

Comment: @hassenzouari I was under the impression you created the application. This changes things. If you have an ssh connection you are already inside a terminal I guess. Do you have a black screen or do you see a user interface? What sort of information do you want to insert? What database are you using?

Comment: @DavidMaes yeah ... user interface , string (it's adsense ca-pub-xxxx and adsense slot number) , mysql ... thanks

Comment: @hassenzouari Ok now we are getting somewhere. No you do not need to use migrations. You do not even need to use a terminal. You just need a program installed to edit the database. You are in luck ;). Check to see if there is a program installed like 'mysql developer'. Or any database editor.

Answer (score 0):

You can run php artisan as usual in your server assuming you deploy the artisan PHP file as well in your root. Running php artisan is literally running a single file called `artisan` which will take the command/argument and do some necessary action.

```
php artisan make:migration add_votes_to_users_table --table=users
```

If you already  have the migration files, just run:

```
php artisan migrate
```

Comment: I'm new in this domain , Can you help me anymore .. where should i excute this ligne ??

Comment: At the root folder of your laravel. If you see there is a file called `artisan`, then that is supposedly the root and can run php artisan

Comment: Just copy it and save !!

Comment: @hassenzouari: When you run on terminal, what does it show?

Comment: I don't know how to run it on terminal :/ please how ? (Because this the first host that i buy )